# How to configure xterm cursor to be a perfect square?

Tags: fonts, cursor

Escape sequences can alter the shape and color of the cursor in a terminal, but how can I change the aspect ratio? When using a square font (e.g. Panoptica), I would like that it prints with the same ratio, i.e. same width than height. Can the grid in a xterm be altered in such a way that whatever you print shows "squared"?

Update: The letters of a perfectly squared font (like Panoptica) will of course show squared, what I want to be square is the box that contains the letter, which keeps being rectangular; that's why I added the reference to the xterm's grid. May be I'm using the wrong terms.

Answer (score 1):

short: no

long: The xterm cursor is drawn to fill (or outline) a cell for a character.  A ***"cell"*** is any row/column combination: each row has several cells, and each column has several cells.  A cell holds no more than one character.  There is no gap between cells (horizontally or vertically).

Since xterm only knows about fixed-pitch fonts, all cells are the same (though you can have double-width characters occupying two cells).

So the cell proportions determine the shape of the rectangle.  It is rare (but not impossible) for a font to use squares.

If Panoptica appears to be square, but xterm is not showing squares, that's probably because

- the Panoptica font header claims that it is not really square, or
- there are some non-square glyphs in the font that you overlooked.

Comment: Your answer provides some interesting information: what is a 'cell' in this context?, if the cell corresponds to the bounding box referred in the question, how can I configure the xterm to have square cells?, does this depend on the font, or is it a property of the xterm?

Comment: @nightcod3r I guess you can check this to change the character cell width/heigth: [determine character cell size of a monospaced TrueType font for xterm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17845086/995714)